# Exclude JUnit from Eclipse exported JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, junit

I'm using Eclipse JUnit integration which includes the JUnit library automatically into my project. The problem is that when I export my project using the *Runnable JAR file* destination, it includes JUnit.

Is there any way to exclude JUnit (and ideally the tests too) from the exported JAR?

Comment: I'm not an Eclipse specialist, but I think that it uses Ant. Am I right? If so, probably your build script have some phases (targets in Ant jargon) that you can interfere, inserting some code to perform some cusomized tasks, in your case, delete the jUnit jar before it is included. I do lots of things like this with NetBeans with no problem. In NetBeans, the phase before the packaging is the "-pre-dist" target.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't use Ant AFAIK. I think maybe an option is to use some kind of Ant integration in Eclipse (assuming such a thing exists) to do the actual building but I'm hoping there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to the problem by using Ant within Eclipse and the following build.xml:

```
<project>
  <target name="jar">
    <jar destfile="out.jar" basedir="bin">
      <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.example.Main" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating your JAR by right clicking on your project and selecting export and then picking JAR File, you can remove your tests from the export by unchecking your test folder.  See [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/631575/) related discussion and [this](http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/jar-libraries.html) example.

Comment: Did you scroll down to this response? http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/198085/633133/#msg_633133

Comment: So to be clear, creating a non-runnable JAR and then editing the manifest to add a Main-Class doesnt work? http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Comment: I think the main problem is that doing it this way, Eclipse doesn't extract and include the libraries my project depends on so my code will fail when it tries to use them.

Comment: It should include everything in the folders that are checked.  If you've set your project up with tests in a separate folder and you uncheck just the test folder, everything should work properly.  The only other thing I can think of is to update the original question and copy/paste the JAR manifest that you're working with into the description.  The steps given in the links that I've provided should work, and are working for other folks per the discussion that is also linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the JUnit package from '.classpath' file.Then export the jar file again

Comment: Wont that break JUnit in Eclipse?